# Every open sub set of $\mathbb R^p$ is the union of countable collection of closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Every open sub set of $\mathbb R^p$ is the union of countable collection of closed sets

My textbook gave me hints as follows :

Let $G$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^p$. Let $A$ be the subset of $G$ whose coordinates are  all rational numbers.

Then, since union of a countable collection of countable sets is a countable set, the set $A$ is countable.

For each $x$ in $A$, there is a smallest natural number $n_x$ such that if $n \geq n_x$,then :

$F_{x,n} = \{y \in \mathbb R^p :|y-x| \leq \dfrac {1}{n}\}$ is contained in $G$

Which is true since $G$ is an open subset in $\mathbb R^p$.

> The problem now seeks to prove that $G=\bigcup \{F_{x,n} :x \in A, n=n_x\}$

But, What about the irrationals. If the above condition is true, where do the irrationals stand? In short, the problems seeks to prove that $G$ is the union of all those $y \in B(x, \dfrac {1}{n})$

I am not able to prove this. Please guide me on how I should move ahead

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You probably mean that $A$ is the set of all points in $G$ with rational *coordinates*. Also, the fact that $A$ is countable can be better described as resulting from the fact that a finite product of countable sets is countable.

Comment: Sorry. I meant that only. Corrected it. So, how can I prove that $G$ is the union of all those $y$ which are contained in the open ball centered at $x$ and radius of $\dfrac {1} {n}$?

Comment: The given union is obviously contained in $G$. Conversely, take an arbitrary point $z \in G$. Try to prove that there is a point $x$ with rational coordinates that is so close to $z$ that $x$ must be in $G$ and $z$ must be in $F_{x,n_x}$.

Comment: So, we have $F_{x,n} \subseteq G  ~~~....(1)$ 

To prove the other way round: Let $x$ be an element in $G$ whose every coordinate is rational. Let $x$ be present in the zero neighborhood of $y \in F_{x,n}$. Then : since, $y$ and $x$ are very close , ... 

Am i going on the right path?

Comment: No. Draw a picture. Since $z$ is an interior point of $G$, you can draw a little ball around it that will be contained in $G$. Give a name to the radius of the little ball. Then see how close you have to make a point $x$ to $z$ in order to guarantee the above two points ($x$ is in $G$ and $z$ is in $F_{x,n_x}$). Then modify your argument a bit to show $x$ can be selected with rational coordinates.

Comment: Let $x \in G$ where $x$ has all rational coordinates. For $x \in G$, we must have the open ball of $x$ of radius $1/m$ to be contained entirely in $G$. For, a point $z \in F_{x,n_x}$, the condition should be $|x- z| \leq \dfrac{1}{n_x} $ ?

Comment: The last part is right, but doesn't answer the question because $n_x$ depends on $x$. Here's an example. Let's say that the ball with radius 0.1 around $z$ is contained in $G$. Now if $x$ is within $0.05$ of $z$, then certainly $x$ will be in $G$. Furthermore, a short argument using the triangle inequality (draw a picture!) will show that the ball of radius 0.05 about $x$ is contained in the 0.1-ball around z, hence in $G$. Thus $n_x \geq 20$, and this allows you to prove that $z$ is in $F_{x,n_x}$. Now repeat the whole argument with $\epsilon$ in place of 0.1.

Comment: Is it just me, or is this method overly complicated for the given statement? Take the set of points whose distance to the complement is at least 1/n, then take the union over positive integers n.  Perhaps it should say "balls" rather than "sets"?

Comment: @Dave If a ball of radius $ϵ$ around $z$ is contained in $G$. Now, $x$ will be contained in $G$ only when $|x−z|<ϵ$. Let $|x−z|=α$. Then α should be less than ϵ. If the ball B(x,α) is centered around x and of radius α, then α must be less than $\dfrac {ϵ}{2}$. or $n_x> \dfrac {2} {ϵ}$ Am I correct? How do i move forward?

Comment: @VHP, "Let $|x-z| = \alpha$ doesn't make sense unless you first say what $x$ is. It's your responsibility here to demonstrate the existence of a suitable $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d(x) = \inf_{y \notin G} \|y-x\| $.

Then $d$ is continuous. To see this, note that
$d(x_1)-d(x_2) \le \|y-x_1\|-d(x_2)$ for all $y \notin G$. Now let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $y \notin G$ such that $d(x_2) > \|y-x_2\|-\epsilon$, then
$d(x_1)-d(x_2) \le \|y-x_1\| -\|y-x_2\|+ \epsilon \le \|x_1-x_2\| + \epsilon$.
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we have $d(x_1)-d(x_2) \le \|x_1-x_2\|$ and by interchanging the roles of $x_1,x_2$ we get $|d(x_1)-d(x_2)| \le \|x_1 -x_2\|$.

Now let $C_n = \{ x | d(x) \ge {1 \over n} \}$. The set $C_n$ is closed since $d$ is continuous, and non-empty for $n$ sufficiently large. In addition, $C_n  \subset G$, and since $G$ is open, if $x \in G$, then $d(x) >0$, hence $x \in C_n$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Hence $G = \cup_n C_n$.

Comment: Is it always possible to choose $y \notin G$ s.t. $d(x_2)-d(x_1) < ||y-x|| - d(x_1)?$

Comment: By definition $d(x_2) = \inf_{x \notin G} \|z-x_2\| \le \|y - x_2\|$ for all $y \notin G$.